# merge to subarray based on their original indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I split this array:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([7,1,2,3,4,5,0])
```

into

```
b=a[a<=2]
c=a[a>2]
```

or

```
b=[1,2,0]
c=[7,3,4,5]
```

Then, I predict b and c:

```
pred_b=[.9,2.01,.02]
pred_c=[7,3,3.85,5.001]
```

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to get this:

```
d=[7,.9,2.01,3,3.85,5.001,.02]
```

Comment: Plz specify, based on what logic you have created that array `d`?

Comment: I want to use different regressions for b and c so they should be separated. Then, I want to classify the results of the previous stage so the predictions should be in their own place so I want to merge b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for your problem:

```
# create an array with the same shape as a
d = np.empty_like(a, dtype=float)
# assign values of pred_b to the slice of indicies of b (like you do in the question snippet)
d[a<=2] = pred_b
d[a>2] = pred_c
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

logical indexing also works for assignment:

```
result = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=float)
result[a<=2] = pred_b
result[a>2] = pred_c
```